# Swift4, How to present another view controller by click button which programmatically created inside current view controller's subview

Tags: swift, swift4

I had programmatically created some UIButtons in UIStackView. The StackView is an subView of original view controller.

How could I present another view controller by click button?

I had try control drag to create segue from original to destination controller and try to use **self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showMealTable", sender: self)** for navigate.

But it throw error at runtime said **"..has no segue with identifier 'showMealTable''"**.

It's my StackView class

```
@IBDesignable class TimeLineHeadControl: UIStackView {
   //MARK: Properties
   private let timeLineControllerInstance = TimeLineController()
   ....
   button.addTarget(self.timeLineControllerInstance, action: #selector(TimeLineController.breakfastButtonTapped(button:)), for: .touchUpInside)
   ....
}
```

And my original view controller

```
class TimeLineController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showMealTable", sender: self)
    }

    ...

    @objc func breakfastButtonTapped(button: UIButton) {
        print("at Time Line Controller")
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showMealTable", sender: self)
    }
    ...

}
```

[Created segue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPgMp.png)

[error message here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpYid.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's talk about the reasons for the error first.

Here:

```
private let timeLineControllerInstance = TimeLineController()
```

This VC you created with the above line is not the same VC that you are seeing in your app. This is another brand new instance of `TimeLineController`, not initialised through the storyboard. Therefore, it does not have the segue.

You need to actually set the VC that is currently presented as `timeLineControllerInstance`.

**However**, either way, you are violating MVC principles. `TimeLineHeadControl` is a view. Views should not be dependent on controllers. Views can send out messages (target-action/delegates) and controllers can choose to listen to these. Controllers choose what views to control, not the other way round.

You should really call `addTarget` in the view controller,

```
// in viewDidLoad
yourStackView.button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(breakfastButtonTapped(button:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

or create a `TimeLineHeadControlDelegate` and use the delegate pattern.

Comment: Thanks! I just implemented delegate pattern to achieve this and navigate by perfomSegue function.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, a segue can't really exist independently of a storyboard. Even if you see the name of the class: UIStoryboardSegue. You cannot create segue programmatically but what you can do is set up the segue in storyboard and then have a function on that button and use the function to perform the action.

Moreover, you can even achieve this without using a segue. You can create a method in your common view controller (base class) that will transition to a new view controller. In your case, base class can be MealViewController and new view controller can be MealTableViewController.

```
- (IBAction)pushNewViewController
{
    NewViewController *newVC = [[NewViewController alloc] init];

    // do any setup you need for newVC like passing data.

    [self presentModalViewController:newVC animated:YES];
}
```

Now you can call this method when the appropriate button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by using code...

```
 @objc func breakfastButtonTapped(button: UIButton) {
        print("at Time Line Controller")
            let vc = self.storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "yourVCidentifier") as! YourVC
        self.present(vc,animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

if you want to do that with segue..
give storyBoard segue identifier to your segue and than call perform segue.